# MSSQLLOCALDB accessibility after deployment

Tags: visual-studio, iis, local-database, data-connections

We get local automatic instance of MSSQLLocalDB while installing visual Studio. 
Why am i not able to access the tables data by having localdb connection string after deployment to IIS

Comment: Is the the mssqllocaldb hosted on the same server with IIS? Which error message you have faced when you could try to access the table data?

Comment: yes i am using the same machine. When I am hitting my application, it says page can't be reached as it couldn't connect to the database.
Basically, I created a asp.net core web api and replaced the Get() method with a code which connects to my db and gets the data from my table to display.
my connection string in the appsetings.json is like "WSRWebAppEF": "Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SampleDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"